# JQuery - Show and hide menu

Tags: jquery

How can I hide the submenu and when the link is clicked, it shows the submenu again...

I tried to do my own code but it doesnt work

I just want to create a simple menu, how can i do that?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<li class="Item1">
     <a href="#" >Separador 1</a>
</li>
<ul class="submenu">
     <li class="menuitem">
         <a href="#"> Submenu 1 </a>
     </li>
</ul>

<style>
li{
   float:left;
   display:inline;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
</style>
<script>
$('.item1 a').click(function() {
      $(this).children('.menuitem').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Comment: You want it to be hidden by default and open when you click the link?

Comment: The HTML snippet you posted is invalid. And JavaScript is case-sensitive, so `$('.item1 a')` should be `$('.Item1 a')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
// `I` capital
$('.Item1 a').click(function() {
    //the submenu is the child of the next li of current li
    $(this).parent().next().children('.menuitem').toggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5A2sJ/)

Comment: Only comment I'd make is to pass the event parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For your jQuery to work, you need to make your submenu a child of the li element:

```
<li class="Item1"><a href="#" >Separador 1</a>

    <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="menuitem"><a href="#"> Submenu 1 </a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And then modify the JS a bit:

```
$('.Item1').click(function() {

    $(this).children('.submenu').find('.menuitem').toggle();

});
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/nD4u8/

You can achieve the same results using your code, but will need to modify the selectors a bit. What I gave you is a bit more standard way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.Item1 a').click(function() {
      $(this).closest('li').next().children().toggle();
});
```

*Note:* You were providing `.item1` class name as markup contains `.Item1` where i is **capital**, so make sure always, selectors are case-sensitive

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2AuLn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='javascript:toggle()'>Expand/Collapse</a>
    <script>
        function toggle(){
        var div1 = document.getElementById('toggle')
        if (div1.style.display == 'none') {
        div1.style.display = 'block'
        } else {
        div1.style.display = 'none'
        }
        }
        </script>

<div id='toggle' style='display:none'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.Item1 a').click(function() {
      $('.submenu li').toggle();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vhsZa/3/)

Answer (score -2):

```
$('.item1 a').click(function() {

      $(this).children('.menuitem').hide();

});
```